# from a geometric construction to an algebraic equation

Tags: geometry

If i want to find a geometric problem leading to the 
algebraic equation $x^5 = 3x + 1$, i might pose the following:

> given a straight segment of length $a$, 
>   construct 5 segments $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$ such that
>   $$a/b = b/c = c/d = d/e = e/f ,$$and
>   $ab = 3af + bf$.

Indeed, letting $x = a/b$, we have 
$$x^5 = (a/b)(b/c)(c/d)(d/e)(e/f) = a/f.$$
Further, $ab = 3af + bf$ leads to  $a/f = 3(a/b) + 1$, 
so $x^5 = 3x + 1$, which is the form i wanted.

My question is: is there a way to relate 
the above geometric problem to other known and meaningful ones?
In general, what type of geometric problems lead to algebraic equations
of some specific degree?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any general method.

The classic Greek problem on angle trisection leads to cubics.

See 
A. M. Gleason,  Angle trisection,  the heptagon,  and the
triskaidecagon, Amer. Math. Monthly, 95(1988), 185-194.

It's on line here: http://poncelet.math.nthu.edu.tw/disk5/js/geometry/reg-polygon/gleason.pdf